# Using IOptions and load options from database with multi tenant application

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I move an application to .net core and trying to use IOptions pattern.

My application is multi tenant with single database. System has global default options and I keep them in database (same as my old application) and also each tenant has own options. If tenant has no option with a key in global, so I need to use global option.

In configuration, I handle to getting global options from database. It is easy with example in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider).

However, each tenant options not going well. Although I actually know what I want, I don't know how to do it in .Net Core.

I test in a console application.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var services = ConfigureServices();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        serviceProvider.GetService<App>().Run();
    }

public class App {
    private readonly IOptionsSnapshot<DemoOptions> _options;

    public App(IOptionsSnapshot<DemoOptions> options) {
        _options = options;
    }

    public void Run() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from App.cs");
        Console.WriteLine($"DemoOptions:Global:Enabled={_options.Value.Enabled}");
        Console.WriteLine($"DemoOptions:Global:AutoRetryDelay={_options.Value.AutoRetryDelay}");
        Console.WriteLine($"DemoOptions:Global:IdentityOptions:MaxUserNameLength={_options.Value.IdentityOptions.MaxUserNameLength}");
    }
}

    private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices() {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        //Load global configuration from database and use them.
        var config = LoadConfiguration();
        services.AddSingleton(config);
        
        services.AddDbContext<EntityConfigurationContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDb"));
        services.AddScoped<ITenantService, TenantService>();

        
        //I take this part from example link in below. But I am not successed.
        services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitorCache<DemoOptions>,TenantOptionsCache<DemoOptions>>();
        services.AddTransient<IOptionsFactory<DemoOptions>,TenantOptionsFactory<DemoOptions>>();
        services.AddScoped<IOptionsSnapshot<DemoOptions>,TenantOptions<DemoOptions>>();
        services.AddSingleton<IOptions<DemoOptions>,TenantOptions<DemoOptions>>();


        // required to run the application
        services.AddTransient<App>();

        return services;
    }

    public static IConfiguration LoadConfiguration() {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.Sources.Clear();

        builder.AddEntityConfiguration(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDb"));

        IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = builder.Build();
        DemoOptions options = new();
        configurationRoot.GetSection($"{nameof(DemoOptions)}:{DemoOptions.Global}").Bind(options);

        Console.WriteLine($"DemoOptions:Global:Enabled={options.Enabled}");
        Console.WriteLine($"DemoOptions:Global:AutoRetryDelay={options.AutoRetryDelay}");
        Console.WriteLine($"DemoOptions:Global:IdentityOptions:MaxUserNameLength={options.IdentityOptions.MaxUserNameLength}");

        return builder.Build();
    }
}

public record DemoOptions {
    public const string Global = nameof(Global);
    public const string Tenant = nameof(Tenant);

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan AutoRetryDelay { get; set; }
    public IdentityOptions IdentityOptions { get; set; }
}

public record IdentityOptions {
    public int MaxUserNameLength { get; set; }
}

public record DemoSettings(string Key, string Value) {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public record TenantSettings(string Key, string Value, int TenantId) {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I add some important class here. However if you want to look at all project, I add [github link](https://github.com/iozcelik/TenantOptionTest).
I use [this example](https://michael-mckenna.com/multi-tenant-asp-dot-net-core-application-tenant-specific-configuration-options)

Answer (score 0):

I see.
You ought to do these things

1. install a nuget package

> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions

2. In your Programs.cs in  ConfigureServices replace this code

```
    var config = LoadConfiguration();
    services.Configure<DemoOptions>(config.GetSection($"{nameof(DemoOptions)}:{DemoOptions.Global}"));
    services.AddSingleton(config);
```

Comment: I fix the code. When creating demo project, I miss same names. But still I have no solution

Comment: I see.
You ought to these things

1. install a nuget package  Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
2. In your Programs.cs in  ConfigureServices after `var config = LoadConfiguration();` add 
`services.Configure<DemoOptions>(config.GetSection($"{nameof(DemoOptions)}:{DemoOptions.Global}"));`

Comment: But I global options are ok. Problem is tenant based

Comment: In your EntityConfigurationProvider you don't load tenant settings `Data = dbContext.DemoSettings.Any() ? dbContext.DemoSettings.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value) : CreateAndSaveDefaultValues(dbContext);`
You should also load tenant settings.
Consequently, your configurationRoot contains only DemoSettings

Comment: Ok I know. I try to find best aproach. When I need to load tenant setting. How I keep in cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can try ready-to-use [JsonRepositoryConfiguration](https://github.com/Shoeib-Yarmand/Json-repository-configuration) Nuget package. It also has a auto-refresh feature and works pretty much like configuration form JSON config files, only it expects the JSON config from **your** repository which can in turn bring the data from any internal/external storage including making a database call, API call etc.

You can mix different configuration provides (like this one and JSON config files) and use them together should you like to. Confession: I am the author.

The next step would be using [Named Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named).